# Texture paint in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting

Helo, i am having this weird problem. I watched a few paint tutorials but couldnt find a solution. I am trying to paint burn on my walls , Made 2 UV maps and everything but when i paint on my wall, it paints everywhere, and thats not whant i want , i dont what else i can do! i unwrapped both maps using the smart UV project. can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]~

[image]

Comment: hello, please pack your images and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: What did you need the second mapping for if they are both using the same Smart Unwrap type of mapping? Double check that you don't have repeated geometry or uv island overlap...

Comment: @moonboots maximum size is30mb for blend stack and for paste all 24mb i couldt upload it even deleting the floor and other stuff in the scene. my file is 31mb

Comment: @CraigDJones one for the brick and other for burn texture

Comment: Try to do Save As → check the compress option in the sidebar before saving. Or eventually remove the textures from your file, we don't really need them as long as we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @L0Lock thank you for the information. i added the file now

Comment: @L0Lock isnt it because my UV text is smaller than the layout? i just realised it now, but how can i make my text bigger in UV editor? i always need to scale the layout because the bricks looks too large

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select the UV map you want to use with your painted texture.

[image: demo gif]

Comment: Hi, i select the dirt  map , scaled the bricks again and i am getting the same problem